# How to correctly deploy changes after pairing Google Cloud Run with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting, angular-universal, google-cloud-run

I just dockerized my Angular Universal application and created a Google Cloud Run service with the created docker image to render the HTML on the server. Furthermore, since it was a Firebase project already using Firebase Hosting, I paired Cloud Run with Firebase Hosting (see ref. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run?hl=en).

**1) create `Dockerfile` in root:**

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy local angular/nest code to the container
COPY . .
# Build development app
RUN npm run build:ssr
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

**2) Add docker container to Google Container Registry**

`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/CONTAINER_NAME --timeout=1200`

**3) Create Cloud Run service with the new container**

`gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/CONTAINER_NAME`

**4) Update `firebase.json` to pair Hosting with Cloud Run**

`firebase.json`:

```json
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "SERVICE_NAME",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
      "region": "europe-west3"      // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
    }
  } ]
}
```

Following this guide, I managed to make it work as expected. However, now I´m confused on how to properly deploy code changes in the future. Before Cloud Run, I just ran `firebase deploy --only hosting` to push the changes onto the static server. I´m new to docker and containers, but now it seems like I have to deploy every code change to Firebase Hosting and additionally to Cloud Run (and also probably create a new container for every little change before?).

Comment: What types of changes are "every little change"? Program code, HTML, etc. Are you in developer mode or production mode. Firebase/CloudRun integrates request processing, not the actual deployment of containers.

Comment: Yes, with "every little change" I basically meant changes to the code of the Angular application. I´m in production mode, however, I use a production server (https.//www.domain.com) and a testing server (https.//www.test.domain.com), each with its own Firebase project. They have the same deployment config except different API keys for Firebase.
The current process is 1) make changes, 2) build code, 3) deploy dist-folder to Firebase Hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source are now in the container. If you need to redeploy your sources, repackage the container and deploy it again.

But, you can also do differently. If you have static sources, you can host them directly on Firebase hosting. It's recommended to host only the backend on Cloud Run. You can play with the `source` parameter and to route only the backend URL to a Cloud Run container. (don't forget to set up the CORS because the Cloud Run URL and the Firebase URL won't be the same!)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. So in this case I´d need to run the two commands: `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/CONTAINER_NAME --timeout=1200` and `gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/CONTAINER_NAME` every time I update the project.

Or can I completely omit these two commands by setting up `continuous deployment` for the Cloud Run service through GitHub triggers?

Comment: Yes, you can do this in a GitHub trigger and use Cloud Build to do this.